# Table Alignment with Div

Tags: html, css, alignment, css-tables

I needed some help with table alignment. I haven't coded for a while, and can't figure out what I am doing wrong here. I have these divs setup, and a table in one, but for some reason the table does not align to the middle. It just aligns with the left side of the table, and the rest leads off to the right. Here is my code:

```
<div id="SlideShow_Wrapper" align="center">
    <div id="SlideShow_Background" align="center">
        <div align="center" id="SlideShow">
            <table border="1" align="center" >
                <tr align="center">
                    <td style="padding-right:15px;"><img src="LeftArrow.png"  /></td>
                    <td><img id="SlideShow_Picture" src="Ore_Background.png"  /></td>
                    <td style="padding-left:15px;"><img src="RightArrow.png"  /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is my css:

```
#SlideShow {
    margin:0px auto;
}
#SlideShow_Background {
    background-image:url(Stone.png);
    border-radius:10px;
    width:820px;
    height:420px;
}
#SlideShow_Wrapper {
    padding-top:50px;
}
```

I tried some things out, and when I remove the `SlideShow_Background`, the table aligns as normally, but when I add it back in, the table just aligns to the right. Any help would be nice

*EDIT:*
I want the table to be centered, not off to the right. This [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7CctF) shows it, but without the content, but you can see what I mean.
And this next link is how I want it to be, [jsfiddle.net/fuECu](http://jsfiddle.net/7CctF) see how it's centered, But I cant find a way to do that without taking off the `SlideShowbackground` div.

Comment: use jsfiddle.net to show your problem.

Comment: @iqbal I checked it...your table is aligning in center so what do you want with it... plz clear

Comment: I see on the second jsFiddle, its still centered, but the page gets bigger, other than the first jsFiddle, its  just plain centered. The code makes the table appear aligned to the right, on my actual html page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table is centered already. The `SlideShow_Background` division just create a horizontal scroll bar on small screens. But still if you scroll the bar to the middle, you will see that table is on the center.

Still if you want the table to be centered, you don't have to remove the `SlideShow_Background`. Just remove the height and width attribute of the div. And it will be set to auto.

```
#SlideShow_Background{
background-image:url(Stone.png);
border-radius:10px;
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7CctF/1/)

Comment: Thank you! This actually fixed the table alignment problem, and not it is Actually centered, but the only problem with this is that it shows the background behind 2 of the table columns, when i only want it to be a background behind the middle column. Otherwise thanks for the help, it helped with the alignment!